# Data.head() was working fine before but now it no longer displays the dataset

Tags: variables, knn

I'm trying to create a KNN working script and I am following a youtuber but when I tried to make adjustment, it stops working. All I changed was the variable names and then going backward and the variables stop working. I had to stop myself from smacking the computer out of frusration

def read_data(csv_file):
data=pd.read_csv('country_vaccinations_by_manufacturer.csv')

data.head()

I've add data into a function to get it to work but if I remove def then pd is not defined but I confirmed pandas is installed. Then I tried to add print function to data.head() and nothing changed